# Why does const prevent this from compiling?

Tags: c++, constants

I am not sure how to fix this problem without creating an extra variable. Here is the code that does not compile:

```
std::string & printVec(std::vector<double> const &ds, std::string &dum) {
    std::vector<double>::iterator it;
//    std::vector<double> dsi = ds; // Created just to get the code to work, using dsi.begin() etc. 
    dum = " ";
    for (it = ds.begin(); it != ds.end(); it++) { // Compiler error. No suitable "="
        dum = dum + std::to_string(*it) + " ";
    }
    return dum;
}
```

If I remove the const on the input, it compiles:

```
std::string & printVec(std::vector<double> &ds, std::string &dum) {
    std::vector<double>::iterator it;
    dum = " ";
    for (it = ds.begin(); it != ds.end(); it++) {
        dum = dum + std::to_string(*it) + " ";
    }
    return dum;
}
```

I have reasons to want the const. What is a way to get the same functionality but not remove the const?

Comment: `std::vector<double>::iterator` -> `std::vector<double>::const_iterator`.

Comment: Since C++11 it's easier to write the loop as either `for (auto it = ds.begin(); it != ds.end(); it++)` or `for (double d : ds) { dum = dum + std::to_string(d) + " "; }`

Comment: An `iterator` can be used to change the element of a vector, so cannot be used on a `const` vector.  Use `const_iterator` instead.

Comment: Thanks. I prefer not to use auto, so as to improve my understanding. I thought of this basic issue. Note that I do not attempt to change the variable, so I thought the compiler would be OK with the code. I guess once one defines a regular iterator referencing a const variable, the compiler could lose track of what happens, and the variable **could** be changed, even if the code as written does not change it. so the compiler prevents that. For example, I could have passed the non-const iterator to a function in another source file, this could wreak havoc, etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A `const_iterator` is an iterator that points to const value (like a const T* pointer); dereferencing it returns a reference to a constant value (const T&) and prevents modification of the referenced value: it enforces [const-correctness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Const_(computer_programming)).

When you have a const reference to the container, you can only get a const_iterator.

Change the iterator to const_iterator:

```
std::vector<double>::const_iterator it;
```

or use [auto](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/auto):

```
for (auto it = ds.begin(); it != ds.end(); it++) { // Compiler error. No suitable "="
    dum = dum + std::to_string(*it) + " ";
}
```

or [range based for loop](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for):

```
for (auto a: ds)
    dum = dum + std::to_string(a) + " ";
```

Comment: If your problem has been solved, don't forget to up-vote and select this as accepted answer.